# There is an error when making Docker Image in rails project(cannot install mysql-client)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, dockerfile

When I tried to build an docker image in my rails project. There was an error with the installation of mysql-client.
The error message was like this:

```
=> E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate
```

Thank you for reading!!

Comment: please add your Dockerfile to question

Comment: The error suggests that whatever image you're building `FROM` doesn't have a package named `mysql-client` in their repositories (or it does it exist but you haven't updated the repos before trying to install the package). We'd need a `Dockerfile` for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you're following instructions which were written when the Docker images were based on Ubuntu. At some point, these older images were changed to base off of Debian. This has caused lots of breakage.

To fix this particular error, change `mysql-client` to `default-mysql-client` in your `Dockerfile`.